# Trying to find a formula for $\sum_{k=0}^n 3\cdot2^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I am aware that $$\sum_{k=1}^n ar^{k-1}=\frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$$
So I tried $\sum_{k=0}^n 3\cdot2^k$ = $\frac{3(1-2^n)}{1-2}$
To get $3(2^n-1)$ which is wrong

Can someone point out my mistake please?

Comment: The $k$ index in your referenced formula is different from the one in your problem... I suspect it is misquoted, since the real formula usually looks like $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}ar^k$...

Comment: @abiessu, there's another problem as well: the displayed equation, to be correct, should start the sum at $k=1$, not $k=0$.

Comment: @BarryCipra My mistake, I remembered the formula wrong. How would I apply the correct formula to my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your formula should is off by one in the exponent.  As you quote it the exponents would run from $-1$ to $n-1$.  They should run from $0$ to $n-1$.  In your question they run from $0$ to $n$, so the exponent on the right should be $n+1$.  You also may not have noticed that the denominator is negative, which accounts for the fact that the numerator is negative too.

Comment: So instead it should be $3(2^{2n+1}-1)$?

Comment: No.  If the sum goes up to $2^n$ it should be $3(2^{n+1}-1)$